# Pasting non-empty array values into Excel

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I'm using the code below to loop through a array(populated from a range) and then add the value of the cell to another array, then I paste the new array into a table in Excel. It's working fine but it also pastes all the empty array values into the table as well, this is a problem as I have a drop down list using that table and it contains lots of empty values at the end.

Is there a way I can either remove the empty values from the array or only paste the values which aren't empty?

```
Sub newFilterStaff()

Dim sourceData, targetData() As Variant
Dim sourceRange, targetRange, rng As Range
Dim sheet As Worksheet
Dim i, staffCount As Integer
Dim time As Long
Dim name As String

time = GetTickCount

'Set default values
staffCount = 0
Set sheet = Worksheets("wfm_staff")

Set sourceRange = sheet.[C1:C100]
sourceData = sourceRange.Value

'sheet.Range("E2:E50").Clear 'Clear previous list

For i = LBound(sourceData, 1) To UBound(sourceData, 1)

    If sourceData(i, 1) <> "XXXX" And i <> 1 Then 'Remove header row

    Set rng = sheet.Range("A" & i)

    With rng
    name = .Value
    End With

    ReDim Preserve targetData(0 To staffCount) 'Add name to array
    targetData(staffCount) = name
    staffCount = staffCount + 1

    End If

Next

Range("E2:E" & UBound(targetData) + 1) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(targetData)

Debug.Print GetTickCount - time, , "ms"

End Sub
```

Comment: Are there any blanks within **sourceRange** or only at the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then just check for blanks:

```
Sub newFilterStaff()

Dim sourceData, targetData() As Variant
Dim sourceRange, targetRange, rng As Range
Dim sheet As Worksheet
Dim i, staffCount As Integer
Dim time As Long
Dim name As String

time = GetTickCount

'Set default values
staffCount = 0
Set sheet = Worksheets("wfm_staff")

Set sourceRange = sheet.[C1:C100]
sourceData = sourceRange.Value

'sheet.Range("E2:E50").Clear 'Clear previous list

For i = LBound(sourceData, 1) To UBound(sourceData, 1)

    If sourceData(i, 1) <> "XXXX" And i <> 1 Then 'Remove header row
        If sourceData(i, 1) <> "" Then

            Set rng = sheet.Range("A" & i)

            With rng
                name = .Value
            End With

            ReDim Preserve targetData(0 To staffCount) 'Add name to array
            targetData(staffCount) = name
            staffCount = staffCount + 1
        End If
    End If

Next

Range("E2:E" & UBound(targetData) + 1) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(targetData)

Debug.Print GetTickCount - time, , "ms"

End Sub
```

Comment: Also had to change `Range("E2:E" & UBound(targetData) + 1)` to `Range("E2:E" & staffCount + 1)`

Comment: You might also consider using **Copy/Paste** rather than the array-to-array transfer.

Comment: I thought about that, but I assumed just copying it to the array then pasting the whole array would be a faster way of doing it

Answer (score 0):

```
If name <> "" Then
        targetData(staffCount) = name
        staffCount = staffCount + 1
End If
```